# HTML, stop elements on page from moving when browser is resized

Tags: html, css, element

Hello i am trying to stop elements from moving when the browser gets resized, for example when i make the chrome window smaller everything starts moving towards the left in a different position, including the text that overlaps the menu bar, Can i keep it in the same position even when i resize the window?

This is the start of my HTML code:

```
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/alternativeCSS2.css" 
title="bigsheet"/>
  <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="css/alternativeCSS2.css" title="mediumsheet"/>
  <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="css/alternativeCSS3.css" title="smallsheet"/>
  <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="css/alternativeCSS4.css" title="specialsheet"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script/CTEC1800-Stylesheets(4).js" >
</script>
  <title>Historical Pioneers</title>
</head>
<body onload="chooseStyleBySize()">
  <div id="layout">
     <div id="swapping">
        <p>
           <select onchange="setActiveStyle(this.value)">
              <option value="bigsheet">For big pages</option>
              <option value="mediumsheet">For medium-sized pages</option>
              <option value="smallsheet">For small pages</option>
              <option value="specialsheet">For special pages</option>
           </select>
        </p>
     </div>
     <div id="header">
        <h1 id="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" width="200px" height="70px" 
alt="logo" /></h1>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div id="nav" class="box">
     <ul class="nav">
        <li id="active"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Hitlers Biography.html">Adolf Hitler's Biography</a>
</li>
        <li><a href="Winston Churchill.html">Winston Churchill's 
Biography</a></li>
        <li><a href="About Us.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="Contact Us.html">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="container" class="box">
     <div id="intro">
        <div id="intro-in">
           <h1>60 million men fought in 'The War to End All Wars', It ended 
nothing..</h1>
           <p class="intro">
              "Putting history in it's place". For many years we have been 
collecting, researching and interpreting historical information from the 
World War 2, How the key figures including Adolf Hitler and Franklin D. 
Roosevelt influenced this great war between 1939 to 1945. 
              Some information that was not yet looked into properly that 
was very well important and how it all began in the first place.
           </p>
        </div>
        <div  id="hr">
           <hr />
```

This is my CSS Code:

```
/*--------------------- Main Body --------------------- */

* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 }
body, div, span, p, a, img, ul, ol, li, table, th, tr, td, form, fieldset, 
legend, dl, dt, dd, blockquote, applet, object {
border: 0;
}
p {
margin: 15px 0;
}
body {
padding: 0;
background-color: #ededed;
background: #fff url("../img/bg1.jpg") repeat-y;
font: 0.8em/1.5 "arial", sans-serif;
color: #354146;
text-align: center;
width: 100%; 
}

#layout {
}

#header{
text-align: left;
margin-left: 30px;
}

#swapping{
text-align: left;
margin-left: 45px;
}

#container{
margin-left: 40%;
clear: both;
width: 100%; 

}

/*--------------------- Horizontal Navigation Menu --------------------- */

#nav {
margin: 0;
height: 100%;
margin-top: 20px;
}
#nav ul {
list-style-type: none;
width: 14%;
min-width:265px;
height: 100%;

clear: both;
```

[text overflowing to the menu bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYNeC.jpg)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You can give a fixed width to `body`or your page wrapper but you should consider to make your website mobile friendly.

Comment: You need to consider **Responsive** web design, to take control over elements in different viewports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by fixing width of your html body, but that doesn't make sense since you want to build **RESPONSIVE** web sites, not fixed ones which work only on certain resolutions!

Just type this in your CSS:

```
body{
    width: [pixel_size]px;
}
```